# Erro em Query Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma página em php que precisa fazer uma consulta em 3 campos no Banco Mysql.

```
Campo Aprovado
Campo Reprovado
Campo Resolution

$select = mysql_query("select * from denuncia where (resolution is NOT NULL) 
AND status='aprovado' or status='reprovado'");
```

Esta Query só retorna o campo Reprovado, porem preciso que retorne tudo que estiver com status aprovado, reprovado e o campo Resolution não for nulo.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: O erro deve estar na precedência dos operadores lógicos, tente: `"select * from denuncia where (resolution is NOT NULL) 
AND (status='aprovado' or status='reprovado)'"`

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado desta forma. Retorna este erro: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: O que está passando como argumento para o `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: A variavel select desta query : while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){

Comment: Tente executar a função `echo mysql_error();` após a linha `$select = mysql_query("...");`.

Comment: Erro de sintaxe    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Desculpe, há um erro de sintaxe na query que sugeri, a última aspas ficou fora do parenteses, corrigindo: `select * from denuncia where (resolution is NOT NULL) AND (status='aprovado' or status='reprovado')`.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Você deve escrever a sua consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
select * from denuncia where resolution IS NOT NULL AND (status='aprovado' OR status='reprovado')
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. Apenas acrescentei como sugestão do @PanterA 3 acima, os parenteses nos campos Status tb. Obrigado.